# ¿Es posible capturar errores cuando usamos fopen/fwrite en PHP?

Tags: php, excepciones

Estaba haciendo pruebas con un código que utiliza la función `fopen` de PHP para manejar un archivo y `fwrite`para escribir dentro del archivo abierto.

Este es el código. Se trata de escribir un conjunto de resultados de la base de datos en el archivo:

```
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        $archivo = 'text/archivo.txt';
        $handler = fopen($archivo,'w');
        /*Verificamos que el recurso se abrió*/
        if($handler)
        {
            //var_dump($handler);
            /*Encabezados*/
            fwrite($handler,str_pad('ID',5));
            fwrite($handler,str_pad('NOMBRE',15));
            fwrite($handler,str_pad('APELLIDO',15));
            fwrite($handler,PHP_EOL);
            /*Contenido*/
            foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
            {
                $intId=$row["actor_id"];
                $strNombre=$row["actor_nombre"];
                $strApellido=$row["actor_apellido"];
                fwrite($handler,str_pad($intId,5));
                fwrite($handler,str_pad($strNombre,15));
                fwrite($handler,str_pad($strApellido,15));
                fwrite($handler,PHP_EOL);
            }

            fclose($handler);
            $txtContent = file_get_contents($archivo);
            $txtHTML = htmlentities($txtContent);
        }
        else
        {
            $txtHTML='No se pudo abrir el archivo';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $txtHTML="La consulta no arrojó datos";
    }
```

Revisando el Manual de PHP, dice que tanto `fopen` como `fwrite` devuelven `FALSE` cuando ocurre algún problema. Pero yo quisiera informar en mi código del problema específico que está ocurriendo: por ejemplo, si el usuario no tiene permisos de lectura o escritura en la carpeta donde se encuentra el recurso, o cualquier otro error. Por eso quisiera saber **si hay alguna manera de obtener los errores específicos cuando se usan `fopen` o `fwrite`**.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner un try-catch y en el catch utilizar IOException, además de mostrar el error por pantalla con el método 'printStackTrace()'.Ejemplo: `try{ //codigo a ejecutar con los archivos }catch(IOException $e){echo $e->printStackTrace()}`